# Finding an approximation of a function's root

Tags: calculus, numerical-methods, self-learning, approximation

I have the polynomial function $f (x) = x^5+2x^2+1$.

I am trying to find an approximation to its root in $[-2,-1]$, with the precision of $0.1$, and with a minimal number of steps. The answer I was given was $-17/16$. I find it incorrect, and I wish to ask for your assistance.

I have calculated $f(-2)$ and $f(-1)$, and found different signs. I then took $f(-1.5)$, $f(-1.25)$ and so on. I found that $f(-1.34375)=0.23$ and $f(-1.359375)=0.054$. Therefore, my calculations show that a precision of $0.1$ cannot be reached, and that the answer is incorrect.

What am I doing wrong ? Thank you.

Comment: You "lost" the change of sign somewhere, double check your computation. The given answer is indeed wrong.

Comment: Thank you. I can't see where I missed the sign change. My values were: -23 , 2 , -2.09375 , 1.073242188 , -.133636475 , 0.5504102709 , 0.2301351132 , 0.0538942291

Comment: I am dividing the range, knowing that the function is continuous. For example, if f(-2)<0 and f(-1)>0, I am looking at f(-1.5).

Comment: Sorry your computation is correct, but why do you stop and conclude that the accuracy cannot be reached ?

Answer (score 3):

As you appear to be using the bisection method you should have:

Step1

```
a=-2, b=-1, c=-1.5; f(a)=-23, f(b)=+2, f(c)=-2.0938
```

Step2:

```
a=-1.5, b=-1, c=-1.25; f(a)=-2.0938, f(b)=+2, f(c)=1.0732
```

Step3:

```
a=-1.5, b=-1.25, c=-1.375; f(a)=-2.0938, f(b)=+1.07324, f(c)=-0.13364
```

So we now have the root is in the interval $(-1.375,-1.25)$ and the mid point of this interval $-1.3125$ is within $0.0625$ of the end points and so within $0.1$ of the root.

Answer (score 1):

We can use [Newton's method](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Newton%27s_method)

$$x_{k+1} = x_k - \dfrac{f (x_k)}{f' (x_k)} = x_k - \dfrac{x_k^5 + 2 x_k^2 + 1}{5 x_k^4 + 4 x_k}$$

with initial guess, say, $x_0 = -2$. In Haskell:

```
λ take 10 $ iterate (\x->x-(x**5+2*x**2+1)/(5*x**4+4*x)) (-2)
[-2.0,-1.6805555555555556,-1.4768055489926624,-1.383795516323458,-1.364705763354018,-1.363965683835678,-1.3639646021027603,-1.3639646021004521,-1.3639646021004521,-1.3639646021004521]
```

Evaluating $f$ and $f'$ at $x_9 = -1.3639646021004521$,

```
λ (\x->x**5+2*x**2+1) (-1.3639646021004521)
-4.440892098500626e-16
λ (\x->5*x**4+4*x) (-1.3639646021004521)
11.849571894907545
```

It can also be shown that

$$\min_{x \in [-2,-1]} |f' (x)| = 1$$

If $|\Delta y| < 5 \cdot 10^{-16}$ and $\min |f'| = 1$, then the magnitude of the error can be bounded as follows

$$|\Delta x| < \frac{5 \cdot 10^{-16}}{1} = 5 \cdot 10^{-16}$$

Thus, in only $9$ iterations we get closer to the root than required.

Comment: Newton is nice, but what guarantee do you have on accuracy ?

Comment: Iterates having close values prove nothing. They could just be a slow-convergence anomaly. Of course I know this isn't the case, but Newton alone provides no guarantee, as opposed to bracketing methods.

Comment: That deserves to be stated in your answer, as the OP has an accuracy requirement. Please do better than the standard "roll Newton" solution.

Comment: @YvesDaoust I made a stupid mistake. I used the maximum of the slope, rather than the minimum. I have corrected that mistake.

Answer (score 1):

By dichotomy, every iteration halves the uncertainty. Hence four iterations will be enough, requiring six function evaluations (five if the presence of a root is guaranteed in the initial interval).

- $f(-2)=-23<0,f(-1)=2>0\implies x\in(-2,-1),$
- $f(-\frac32)=-2.09375<0\implies x\in(-\frac32,-1),$
- $f(-\frac54)=1.07324>0\implies x\in(-\frac32,-\frac54),$
- $f(-\frac{11}8)=-0.13363<0\implies x\in(-\frac{11}8,-\frac54),$
- $f(-\frac{21}{16})=0.550410>0\implies x\in(-\frac{11}8,-\frac{21}{16}).$